# Transpose multilevel index pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I need to transpose a dataframe from

```
Month  Year   Count
1      2013   4456
       2014   3321
       2015   3316
       2016   6798
2      2013   4123
       2014   4490
       2015   5689
```

and so on into one that looks like

```
Year   1     2
2013   4456  4123
2014   3321  4490
2015   3316  5689
2016   6798  NaN
```

various attempts, including looking at [MultiLevel index to columns : getting value_counts as columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971381/multilevel-index-to-columns-getting-value-counts-as-columns-in-pandas)
havent worked.

On edit - The unstack method didn't work (or i didn't know how to use it correctly) however the pivot with reset_index, works perfectly.

My first problem seems to be a total misunderstanding of indexes and multi indexes as Month Year are a multi-index (as per looking at the dataframe) but any attempts to index with df['Month'] or other combinations always fail.

Would really love some help here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MultiLevel index to columns : getting value\_counts as columns in pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971381/multilevel-index-to-columns-getting-value-counts-as-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: Your solution below, using pivot and reset_index, solved the problem for me in a manner different that the linked answer which uses unstack. Same problem different solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html). You may need to use `reset_index` first.

```
df = df.reset_index().pivot('Year', 'Month', 'Count')
```

Alternatively, you can use the `unstack` function, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11972498/3175431).

Comment: It's all so simple when you see the answer. Previous attempts had also used pivot_table, which obviously failed :)